# Gradle DSL method not found 'compile()

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm making an interactive login app with Android Studio and wampserver. After creating the Android Studio project, I changed the `build.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies { 

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Then the IDE keeps showing the following error:

```
(((Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()
Possible causes:The project 'Login_wamp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin )))
```

When I click on *Apply gradle plugin*, it shows me a lot of plugins. Should I pick one of these options?

What should I do to fix this error?

#### UPDATE

I have moved the above lines to the other `build.gradle` file, but I get 2 other problems now:

> the support library should not use the different version(21) than the compileSDK version(23).

These lines are my gradles exact shape. Which "21" should be changed to "23" or which "23" should be changed into "21"?

I have changed the 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` to 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'` and it says that I should *Install Repository and sync project*.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" 
minSdkVersion 14 
targetSdkVersion 23 
versionCode 1 
versionName "1.0" 
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3' 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' 
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' 
}
```

Comment: can you show your full build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the top level build.gradle

```
root
|--app
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle    //top level file
|--settings.gradle
```

In this file you **can't use the** **`compile`** statement:(it is the reason of your issue)
Just move these lines:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        //REMOVE THESE LINES
        //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Then you have to add the dependencies in your module/build.gradle file.

**EDIT**: After your comment.

In your `module/build.gradle`file:

- use the same version for all support libraries
- use the latest (currenlty 23.1.1)
- dont' add the same library twice (appcompat)
- the 23.0.3 doesn't exist

Here the changes:

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'   //update to 23.1.1
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3' //REMOVE THIS LINE. It doesn't exist and you adding twice
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'     //USE THE SAME VERSION
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' 
}
```

Comment: thanks man i finally made it right . i have moved it to the other build.gradle file and i have 2 other problems now , it says that the support library should not use the different version(21) than the compileSDK version(23).
these lines are my gradles exact shape.which (21) should be changed to (23 ) or which (23) should be changed into ( 21) ? i have changed the compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3' TO compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3' and it says that i should Install Repository and sync project.can you tell me what lines should be changed?
thanks alot.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}

Comment: @MehdiMoslehi Use 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'. Same for the other support libraries. The 23.0.3 doesn't exist. Also don't add the appcompat twice.

Comment: @MehdiMoslehi I've edited your question with your comments and I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks man , you did help me a lot . 
and thanks for the edits.

Comment: @MehdiMoslehi  Mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong build.grade file.
There are two gradle files in your Project.

One is called build.gradle (Project: YourProjectname)
The other one build.grade (Module: app).

Delete the following lines from build.gradle (Project: YourProjectname):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

Search the dependencies in your build.gradle (app: Module)

```
dependencies {  
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and add the compile lines there:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir , the problem was solved but i have some minor issues which is new. please read my comment to the upper answer , i will be glad   if help me.

Answer (score -2):

salam Mehdi. first of all you must open `freegate` and set `proxy settings` from android studio settings.(IP=127.0.0.1 and port=8580). after that you must click on apply `gradle plugin` to update your `SDK`. after updates done the error must gone. Hope this help you.

Comment: hello there . i do not think that's the answer , 
my build.gradle was wrong , i should have entered it on the module app instead of the project name .
thanks for your info by the way.

Comment: we are here to help. if the answer is helpful please up vote it.